# Show individual objects as wireframe in 3D viewport

Tags: 3d-view, interface, wireframe

In Viewport Shading settings, one can make all objects shown as wireframes:

[image]

But is it possible to only show a certain object(s) as wireframe, while keeping others in Solid or Material mode?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it from the Object Properties. Change your object's viewport display from "Textured" to Wire :

[image: Wire]